# How to check JArray is empty

Tags: c#, arrays, dotnet-httpclient, is-empty

I am calling an API through a HttpClient and getting a response like follows.

```
{
  "result_set": []
}
```

I parsed the response in to a dynamic object.

```
dynamic dbResponseBody = await dbResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
```

How to check the result_set is empty or not. Currently I am doing as follows but looking for a better way.

```
if (dbResponseBody.Result.result_set != "[]") {}
```

Comment: Think how you would iterate it. I'm not fresh on the syntax, but I assume the dynamic `result_set` would have an indexer of some sort, and a length property. You could check if the length is 0. You might want to check for `string.IsNullOrEmpty(result_set)` in addition to that, to make sure the dynamic property exists in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @Yorye. There is a count property so I have used it. if(dbResponseBody.Result.result_set.Count > 0)

Comment: It seems like it's a json response. Have you tried JSON.NET? You can parse the response to json object and then check if result_set equals to null or an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a model for your response if you know the type.

```
class Response
{
        [JsonProperty("result_set")]
        public List<string> ResultSet { get; set; }
}
```

If your items in your array model are more complex you can construct the following

```
class Response
{
        [JsonProperty("result_set")]
        public List<Items> ResultSet { get; set; }
}

class Items{
     [JsonProperty("P1")]
     public string P1 { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("P2")]
     public int P2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can read your response as follows:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse)
                    {
                        if (response != null && response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                            throw new Exception(String.Format(
                                "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
                                response.StatusCode,
                                response.StatusDescription));

                        if (response != null)
                        {
                            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                            Respose myResponse = GetResponseModel<Response>(responseStream);

                         }
                         else throw new Exception("My message");
```

Using Newtonsoft you can get the model back again

```
protected T GetResponseModel<T>(Stream respStream) where T : class
        {
            if (respStream != null)
            {
                var respStreamReader = new StreamReader(respStream);
                Task<string> rspObj = respStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                rspObj.Wait();

                Debug.WriteLine("Response: {0}", rspObj.Result);

                T jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(rspObj.Result);

                return jsonResponse;
            }

            return default(T);
        }
```

At the end after this line you can check the properties of your model

```
Respose myResponse = GetResponseModel<Response>(responseStream);

if(myResponse.Result.Count == 0){.....}
```

Comment: what if you don't want to construct the model? what if you just want to check if the JArray is empty?